# comparing dates in php

Tags: php

In the following php code, I am trying to show only those products from products.xml file that are stored in the last month. But my code does not work. Please help me in getting correct output. I also need to show products that are stored in the last 24 hours and last week.

```
$current_month = date("m");
$last_month = date('m', strtotime(date('-m')." -1 month"));

$xml = simplexml_load_file("products.xml");

$products = array();
foreach ($xml->product as $product) {
   if ($product->date('m') == $last_month) {
      $products[] = array( 'name' => (string)$product->name,
                           'details' => (string)$video->details );
   }    
}
```

Comment: Show us your xml and a portion of your output.

Comment: are the time intervals relative to the current timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Strtotime is nicer than you might think. For instance, this code;

```
if (date('m') > date('m', strtotime('last month')))
    echo true;
else
    echo false;
```

Will currently output "true" - because last month is 09, and this month is 10.

But what if this month is 01, and last month is 12? Then it would be false. I'd recommend you compare on years as well.

Edit: If this isn't a problem, and you only want to evaluate this for the most recent additions, then that should be fine. But you'll run into problems the year after if you only compare from last month, unless your import data only contains stuff from this year.

Comment: Year will not be a problem because this xml file automatically delete all products stored earlier than two months

Comment: what about for last week and 24 hours??

Comment: Change the argument to strtotime for that. Follow the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $last_month = date('m', strtotime("-1 month"));

 $xml = simplexml_load_file("products.xml");

$products = array();
foreach ($xml->product as $product)
 {
  if ($product->date('m') == $last_month)
   {
$products[] = array(
'name'=>(string)$product->name,
'details'=>(string)$video->details,
    );
   }    
}
```

Comment: what about for last week and 24 hours?

Comment: I tried ur above code but it shows error " call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement:date()

Comment: your line 'if ($product->date('m') == $last_month)' has problem $product has no method date so probably u will need something like "if  (date('m', strtotime($product->date)) == $last_month)" to make it work